# GridMvc wrong shows texts in column

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-encode, grid.mvc

I have a problem with GridMvc library. I want to add column which contains joined table of string with 
 delimiter, here is my code:

```
columns.Add()
       .RenderValueAs(
           row => string.Join(
               HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode("<br/>"),
               row.QuestionDifficultyToPosition.Select(
                   r => r.Difficulty.DifficultyName).ToArray()))
       .Titled("Difficulties")
       .Filterable(true)
       .Sortable(true);
```

but in the result i get:

```
Easy&lt;br/&gt;Hard
```

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: GridMvc wrong shows ??

Comment: Don't HTML encode the <br /> tag.  That results in the rendering you're seeing.

Comment: I found solution: Encoded(false).Sanitized(false)

Comment: Cool - do the site, and future seekers, a favour and post your working code as an answer to your question so we'll know this has been answered.

Comment: This is indeed very good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the encoded `<br/>`, so you need to remove your call to the `HtmlEncode()` method. Also, from the [docs](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Render%20button%2C%20checkbox%20etc%20in%20the%20grid%20cell)...

> you need to disable default encoding and satinizing cell values,
>   using **Encoded** and **Sanitized** method.

```
columns.Add()
       .Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false)
       .RenderValueAs(
           row => string.Join(
               "<br/>",
               row.QuestionDifficultyToPosition.Select(
                   r => r.Difficulty.DifficultyName).ToArray()))
       .Titled("Difficulties")
       .Filterable(true)
       .Sortable(true);
```